# SVM Linear Classifier - Strange Behaviour

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I must be doing something simple wrong here, but I can't figure it out.

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
y = [False, True, True]
X = [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict(1.4)

Out[324]: array([False], dtype=bool)
```

Behaves as expected... yet...

```
X = [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3]]
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict(0.14)

Out[325]: array([True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that sklearn implementation of SVM includes regularization parameter. Lets see how this affects the result.

First of all, in your second example `clf.predict(0.14)` gave `True`. In fact, even `clf.predict(0.1)` gives `True`, which may seem counter intuitive, as in your training example you classify it as `False`.

The difference between your two examples is that in your second example, the points from your different classes are much closer to each other than in the first one. Thus, the margins of the separating hyperplane are going to be much smaller in the second example.

Now, SVM (without regularization) tries to find a separating hyper-plane with largest possible margins, which are going to be rather small in your second example. The formula for the margins is `1/||w||` (see the top of page 7 [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf)). Hence small margins means large `||w||`. SVM will minimize `0.5||w||^2` (under certain constraints, see page 7 [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf)).

However, when you add regularization parameter `C`, SVM will try to minimize `0.5||w||^2+C*penalty` (see the bottom of page 19 [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf)). So it may result in decreasing `||w||` while increasing the penalty. This may increase classification error rate.

The default regularizer in sklearn implementation of SVM is `C=1`. If you take `C=1000` instead, then `clf.predict(0.14)` will give you `False`.